# When printing photos to the Canon TS960 printer from iPhone/iPad using AirPrint, the printer thinks the print job is a CD label

Tags: printing, iphone, ipad

When printing **photos* to the Canon TS960 printer from iPhone or iPad using AirPrint, the printer thinks the print job is a CD label and asks me to 'Place a printable disk on the multi-purpose tray'.  How can I fix this?

*Printing anything but photos works normally.  Also, the issue is specific to iOS devices and doesn't happen when printing photos from my MacBook.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Things like this happen because the *Media Type* definition in the printer is mis-configured.

In this case "Photos" isn't using a tray with photo paper, it's looking for a CD Label because somehow in the printer the media type for photo became "CD Label"

The [User Guide](https://bit.ly/38wunqN) is usually the best place to start with when addressing issues like these and it will be under the section to do with [paper settings or handling](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300025339/02/TS9000ser_OnlineManual_Mac_EN_V02.pdf)